# simple jquery function doesn't work when included in wordpress? help?

Tags: jquery

I'm replacing class name generated by one of the plugins with mine. I found this easier than fiddling with plugin on every upgrade. Anyways, in WP this simply doesn't do anything! When I test it on non wp (same template xhtml) it works!

what could be the conflict? I have jquery included.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".slideright img").removeClass("ngg-singlepic").addClass("cover");
    //$(".ngg-singlepic").addClass("cover");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".slideright img").removeClass("ngg-singlepic").addClass("cover");
    //$(".ngg-singlepic").addClass("cover");
});
```

The problem is that I think wordpress includes other libraries that conflict with the `$` when used with jquery.

To get around this you need to explicitly call `jQuery` the first time and if you pass `$` into the function then it will let you use the familiar `$` within the scope of the jquery function.

Hope that helps.

Comment: nice, thank you also for explaining... I'm learning allot these days :)

Comment: thats ok. :) I'm getting into the habit of ALWAYS doing `jQuery(document).ready(function($){...});` now, even outside of wordpress. Just incase in the future compatibility is needed with other libraries. :) Its a good habit to get into I think. :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is some other framework included in your page. Try the following:

```
jQuery( function($) {
    $(".slideright img").removeClass("ngg-singlepic").addClass("cover");
});
```

And if that does not help, you can even try to put `jQuery.noConflict();` before the snippet.